# WP-API search post and pages in one request

Tags: wordpress, api, search

Is it possible to search for wordpress posts AND wordpress pages in ONE request using the [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) REST API?
?

(By slug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern is right in the [WP-API Documentation's 'Type' section](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts)

`GET /posts?type[]=post&type[]=page`

Comment: Is this still possible with WP-API v2?

Comment: I haven't used the V2 API so I'm not sure. After a quick review of the docs, it doesn't seem like there is. I'd suggest running the `posts` endpoint and see what you get back